# Converting Text Tables Into CSVs in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, tabular, converters

I'm looking to convert tabular data into CSVs, but I'm hitting a roadblock when the table has rows with certain missing values. Input looks like the following table,

```
systemd       1                   root  cwd       DIR                8|1      4096          2 /
systemd       1                   root  rtd       DIR                8|1      4096          2 /
systemd       1                   root  txt       REG                8|1   1612152     101375 /lib/systemd/systemd
systemd       1                   root  mem       REG                8|1   1700792      26009 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.27.so
systemd       1                   root  mem       REG                8|1    121016       1715 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.6.9
node        697   698             user1 cwd       DIR               8|33      4096    7995393 /home/user1
node        697   698             user2 rtd       DIR                8|1      4096          2 /
node        697   698             user1 txt       REG               8|33  43680144    8003081 /home/user1/.vscode-server/bin/26076a4de974ead31f97692a0d32f90d735645c0/node
node        697   698             user1 mem       REG                8|1    101168      26021 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.27.so
node        697   698             user1 mem       REG                8|1     26936      26014 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.27.so
```

I want to convert this into a CSV with the number of columns preserved, the output should look something like,

```
systemd,1,,root,cwd,DIR,8|1,4096,2,/
systemd,1,,root,rtd,DIR,8|1,4096,2,/
systemd,1,,root,txt,REG,8|1,1612152,101375,/lib/systemd/systemd
systemd,1,,root,mem,REG,8|1,1700792,26009,/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.27.so
systemd,1,,root,mem,REG,8|1,121016,1715,/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.6.9
node,697,698,user1,cwd,DIR,8|33,4096,7995393,/home/user1
node,697,698,user2,rtd,DIR,8|1,4096,2,/
node,697,698,user1,txt,REG,8|33,43680144,8003081,/home/user1/.vscode-server/bin/26076a4de974ead31f97692a0d32f90d735645c0/node
node,697,698,user1,mem,REG,8|1,101168,26021,/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.27.so
node,697,698,user1,mem,REG ,8|1,26936,2601,/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.27.so
```

So far I've tried it using pandas read_fwf function and then converting it to CSV, but it's not evaluating the missing column value. So instead of getting 10 values for every row in the CSV, I'm getting only the visible 9. The same thing happens while using pandas read_table function as well. I also tried using Regex Patterns but I'm not expecting the table format to be same every time, upscaling the code to incorporate more tables becomes a problem

Any method to solve this problem is highly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: did you try replacing `""` with `"NaN"` or `np.nan` or any text?

Comment: This issue won't occur when the tables have column headers, its when the input tables are given without column headers that it is causing this trouble.

Comment: @woblob Not really, that would replace every whitespace with the provided text, in some cases, values in one single column can have whitespaces also (description columns, for example)

Comment: if there is no header did you try `pd.read_table(filename, header=None)`  or `header=0` ?

Comment: @woblob I just did, adding the `header=None` part it's skipping the missing value like before

Comment: Will that be the only column that may contain missing values ? In that case, you can try this [code](https://www.codepile.net/pile/xgpD4eg8)

Comment: @SurajSubramanian thanks for the answer, but no, any column can have missing values, sometimes even multiple columns can have missing values.

Comment: Then you gotta fill in NaN's in place of the missing values in your text file before you try out any code.

Comment: @SurajSubramanian that appears to be the solution but I've no way of knowing which values are going to be missing when the text is given to me. The text that I've quoted in the question is merely the tip of the iceberg, the orginal data consists of thousands, maybe tens of thousands of rows. Can you suggest any method to actively replace all the blank values across the data with NaN, again, the code takes care of it if there're column headers.

Comment: @SurajSubramanian then I'll end up writing regex for every format of tabular data that I can ever get, not to mention if a table format changes, I'll have to update its regex as well. I also have to keep adding on new regex patterns for every new table, upscaling the code to fit more types of tabular data will be a huge problem. I tried automated pattern recognition and prediction in the past to solve this, but it becomes really complicated and tedious when the table size (both rows and columns) increases, apart from not being sufficiently accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the problem smaller by splitting your data into valid and invalid rows. Valid rows will have the expected number of columns and invalid will have one or more columns missing. Not sure if you can automate this fully without knowing the exact delimiter between columns.

You mention that spaces can occur in description columns. You can't really differentiate between `user1 cwd` which are two separate columns and a space inside a single column. Rows like that would be put into `invalid` list unless they happen to have a missing value to "balance" it out. It's pretty brittle so best to either make sure you have a proper delimiter or that at least there are no spaces in your column values.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import re

data = StringIO("""
systemd       1                   root  cwd       DIR                8|1      4096          2 /
systemd       1                   root  rtd       DIR                8|1      4096          2 /
systemd       1                   root  txt       REG                8|1   1612152     101375 /lib/systemd/systemd
systemd       1                   root  mem       REG                8|1   1700792      26009 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.27.so
systemd       1                   root  mem       REG                8|1    121016       1715 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.6.9
node        697   698             user1 cwd       DIR               8|33      4096    7995393 /home/user1
node        697   698             user2 rtd       DIR                8|1      4096          2 /
node        697   698             user1 txt       REG               8|33  43680144    8003081 /home/user1/.vscode-server/bin/26076a4de974ead31f97692a0d32f90d735645c0/node
node        697   698             user1 mem       REG                8|1    101168      26021 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.27.so
node        697   698             user1 mem       REG                8|1     26936      26014 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.27.so
""")

valid_rows = []
invalid_rows = []
num_of_columns = 10

for line in data.readlines():
    # note that in your data there is a new line
    # at the end of each line which is also captured by \s
    if len(re.findall(r"\s+", line)) == num_of_columns:
        valid_rows.append(line)
    else:
        invalid_rows.append(line)        

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("".join(valid_rows)), delim_whitespace=True, names=range(10))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this method completely discards the invalid rows, I really can't do that. If a column is blank in all rows, it's going to classify the entire data as invalid. The source which generates this data is beyond my control, so I can't put delimiters inside the data without making that change at the source or actually looking into the data.

Comment: Not quite - it just separates the invalid rows that you can save separately and fix by hand. I'm guessing the column width isn't fixed for the columns either and you can't know ahead of time that the maximum width of column 1 is 7?

Comment: Yes, no way of knowing it beforehand.

Comment: Then I'm afraid it's just messy data that doesn't lend itself to automation very well. All you can do is lessen the pain by taking the good rows and fixing the rest by hand (which might not be as bad if you use text editor with 'column mode').